# capybara poltergeist cant upload file

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

Hello i am trying to upload file with capybara poltergeist, on hidden input. here is my feature file

```
  Scenario: Import csv with valid and invalid entries, and try to charge them again
    And  Joe navigates to "Lottery import" page of "Joe's Test Event"
    And  Joe uploads file from path "/vagrant/tests/capybara/features/admin/lottery_import/step_definition/sample_lottery_entries_list.csv" into "file" field
```

and rb file for import

```
Then(/^(\S*) uploads file from path "([^"]*)" into "([^"]*)" field$/) do |user, file_path, field|
  page.attach_file(field, File.expand_path(file_path), :visible => false)
  waits_for_spinner_by_class_not_visible
end
```

strange this works with Selenuim driver, but not with poltergeist driver.
Any ideas how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File inputs are often hidden for styling reasons, which makes them non-interactable. Because of that capybara's`attach_file` has an option to make it easier to temporarily make the file input visible/interactable

```
page.attach_file field, file_path, make_visible: true
```

That will temporarily apply CSS { opacity: 1, display: 'block', visibility: 'visible' } to the file input element. If that CSS won't make the input visible you can set `make_visible` to a hash that will rather than `true`